Is it possible to convert ssh private key from PEM to OpenSSH format without a salt?
Per https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/wf7ri8/comment/iit1rwx/ to convert a private key from PEM to OpenSSH format I need to first make a copy of the file and then run:
ssh-keygen -p -f private_key_openssh.pem -N ""

The problem is that every time I run this command, a portion of the output keeps on changing as if some random salt was being used. I need a command that will generate consistent output because the value is being used in automated tests.
Is there another way to convert PEM to OpenSSH format? Is there a way to hard-code the changing component to something stable?
UPDATE: As requested, here is a concrete example...
Given this test key in PEM format:
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEIFILtH9SV+gU1C91FN16twvHqxf1tnCIM7gh3Ii6eeR2oAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAEdZ9Uhb8uw4t/dhpjMvCbFhI2330wrpxisGayIKv8iMtQt97neG8T
d1uL21wrWX8j3lW1jaVtXl0mf97lpnCd0g==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----

if I copy /Y private_key.pem private_key_openssh.pem and then ssh-keygen -p -f private_key_openssh.pem -N "" I get this output:
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAaAAAABNlY2RzYS
1zaGEyLW5pc3RwMjU2AAAACG5pc3RwMjU2AAAAQQR1n1SFvy7Di392GmMy8JsWEjbffTCu
nGKwZrIgq/yIy1C33ud4bxN3W4vbXCtZfyPeVbWNpW1eXSZ/3uWmcJ3SAAAAmLDjFkWw4x
ZFAAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBHWfVIW/LsOLf3Ya
YzLwmxYSNt99MK6cYrBmsiCr/IjLULfe53hvE3dbi9tcK1l/I95VtY2lbV5dJn/e5aZwnd
IAAAAgUgu0f1JX6BTUL3UU3Xq3C8erF/W2cIgzuCHciLp55HYAAAAA
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----

If I repeat this process a second time I get this output:
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAaAAAABNlY2RzYS
1zaGEyLW5pc3RwMjU2AAAACG5pc3RwMjU2AAAAQQR1n1SFvy7Di392GmMy8JsWEjbffTCu
nGKwZrIgq/yIy1C33ud4bxN3W4vbXCtZfyPeVbWNpW1eXSZ/3uWmcJ3SAAAAmNyNVafcjV
WnAAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBHWfVIW/LsOLf3Ya
YzLwmxYSNt99MK6cYrBmsiCr/IjLULfe53hvE3dbi9tcK1l/I95VtY2lbV5dJn/e5aZwnd
IAAAAgUgu0f1JX6BTUL3UU3Xq3C8erF/W2cIgzuCHciLp55HYAAAAA
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----

and so on. Every time I run the command, the same subset of the output gets modified, but every time I get a different value.

For the purposes of diagnostics, create a test key in the .pem format and post the converted OpenSSH formatted key. So we can see what output you are getting exactly.

What shell are you running copy /Y private_key.pem private_key_openssh.pem in exactly?


ssh-keygen -p -f private_key_openssh.pem -N "" indicates I need an argument after -N. 2. When I entered text within the quotes, it worked, but it saved my identification with a passphrase.


@Ramhound I am running this under Windows 10's cmd.exe shell. Odd that it requires you to provide a passphrase. Which platform/version are you running under? To clarify, the goal is to create a private key without a passphrase in openssh format.

The behavior is identical on Windows 10 and Windows 11. I am aware what the purpose of the empty quotes is but ssh-keygen did not allow it.

Just use the public key in your unit tests. I.e: you can generate the public key from the private with:
 ssh-keygen -y -f private.key > public.key

By definition if two private keys authenticate against the same public key they are the same private keys.
Additionally you don't need to worry about leaking secrets - if you want to put the public key in source control etc, since the public key is not considered secret.

I am testing the method that converts a PrivateKey object into an OpenSSH representation. Comparing the public key would work, but it's less ideal because we'd be testing indirect output of the method. I'd much rather compare the direct output, if at all possible.
